# TikZ or cryptocode package for cryptographic protocol diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdftex, diagrams

I am using cryptocode package to make a protocol of 4 players.

```
\fbox{
\procedure{name}{%
 \textbf{Alice}  \< \textbf{Verisign}  \< \textbf{Eve}  \< \textbf{Bob} \\
\sendmessageright{top=\text{hello}} \<\\
\<\sendmessageright{top=\text{hello}} \<\\
\<\<\sendmessageright{top=\text{hello}} \<\\
 }
 }
```

I think it is very complex package with no clear documentation. I am writing to ask from experts if it is better to stick to cryptocode or to use TikZ for such diagrams. 
And if any one can help me with this example using TikZ i would appreciate it :-) 
thanks
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know [`msc` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/msc)? It was developed to include Message Sequence Charts. (Note: you should compile with XeLaTeX)
Your example looks:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{msc}

\begin{document}

\drawframe{no}
\begin{msc}{name}
    \declinst{A}{}{Alice}
    \declinst{B}{}{Verisign}
    \declinst{C}{}{Eve}
    \declinst{D}{}{Bob}
    \mess{hello}{A}{B}
    \nextlevel
    \mess{hello}{B}{C}
    \nextlevel
    \mess{hello}{C}{D}
\end{msc}

\end{document}
```

As an alternative you could use `TikZ`. 
With `tikzpeople` you can introduce some fun to all these serious protocols.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{lmodern, tikzpeople}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[people/.style={minimum width=1.5cm}]
\node[people, alice] (alice) {Alice};
\node[people, priest, right=of alice] (vs) {Verisign};
\node[people, nun, right=of vs] (eve) {Eve};
\node[people, bob, right=of eve] (bob) {Bob};

\draw[->] ([yshift=-1cm]alice.south) coordinate (l1)--(l1-|vs) node[midway, above]{Hello};
\draw[->] ([yshift=-1.5cm]vs.south) coordinate (l2)--(l2-|eve) node[midway, above]{Hello};
\draw[->] ([yshift=-2cm]eve.south) coordinate (l3)--(l3-|bob) node[midway, above]{Hello};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```